# Updating array in vuex not reacting in component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to push/pop off an array that is in a vuex module.

when viewing in vue dev tools the array correctly adds/removes.
However the computed property does not update, im expecting a change but it does not work.

In Vuex module

```
// initial state
const state = {
  expandedPayments: []

}

// getters
const getters = {
  expandedPayments(state) {
    return state.expandedPayments
  },


}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  [Mutations.PUSH_PAYMENTID](state, id) {
    state.expandedPayments.push(id)
  },

  [Mutations.POP_PAYMENTID](state, id) {
    _.pull(state.expandedPayments, id)
  }
}
```

In component

```
 <tr v-show="isExpanded">
```

...

```
 isExpanded() {
      return  _.includes(this.expandedPayments, this.paymentId)
    },
    ...mapGetters('payment', ['expandedPayments', 'isExpanded'])
```

Comment: "However the computed property does not update": How can you see that it does not work? Is it in a template? If yes, could you share that template as well?

Comment: @Hammerbot, it is just using a  v-show="isExpanded", if i return true in the isExpanded computed property, it shows fine

Comment: And, just to be sure, are you sure that `this.paymentId` in the component is in the `expandedPayments` array in vuex? Are both showed at the same time in the dev tools?

Comment: @Hammerbot, you were right in your deleted answer. flipping lodash!...i used plain JS and it works now., had to also change the mutation to remove item js way....lodash isn't all to blame though as the vue dev tools were showing the correct values in the arrays

Comment: Ho well, I undelete it then, I thought it was a mistake from me because it worked on runkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is because you are using the `includes` method of lodash here. This method is supposed to check if an element is part of a collection.

You might want to try this out:

```
isExpanded() {
    return  this.expandedPayments.indexOf(this.paymentId) !== -1
}
```